# Mockery: test if argument is an array containing a key/value pair

Tags: php, phpunit, constraints, hamcrest, mockery

How can I use mockery and hamcrest to assert that when a method of a mock object is called, one of the arguments passed to it is an array containing a key/value pair?

For example, my test code might look like this:

```
$mock = m::mock('\Jodes\MyClass');

$mock   ->shouldReceive('myMethod')
        ->once()
        ->with(
                    arrayContainsPair('my_key', 'my_value')
                );
```

I know I could write it with a closure, but I was just wondering if there's another way of making it read slightly better:

```
$mock   ->shouldReceive('myMethod')
        ->once()
        ->with(
                m::on(function($options){
                    return 
                        is_array($options) &&
                        isset($options['my_key']) &&
                        $options['my_key'] == 'my_val';
                })
            );
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer by looking through the [Hamcrest PHP code here](https://github.com/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/blob/master/hamcrest/Hamcrest/Arrays/IsArrayContainingKeyValuePair.php),

The function name is given away in the doc comment:

```
 * @factory hasEntry
```

So my code will look like this:

```
$mock   ->shouldReceive('myMethod')
        ->once()
        ->with(
                    hasEntry('my_key', 'my_value')
                );
```

Comment: Is there any way to test that array has two keys?

Comment: @DimitryK Hamcrest let's you combine conditions which may work. E.g `allOf(hasEntry('my_key1', 'my_value1'), hasEntry('my_key2', 'my_entry2'))`. Also, Mockery has `Mockery::subset()` which may also be what you want. E.g. `\Mockery::subset(['my_key1' => 'my_value1', 'my_key2' => 'my_entry2'])`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in another solution you can check [Ouzo mocking](http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/documentation/tests.html#mocking).

Simply you can do this:

```
//creating mock
$mock = Mock::create('MockTestClass');

//call mock
$mock->test(['key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2']);

//asserts (verification)
Mock::verify($mock)->test(Mock::argThat()->extractField('key1')->equals('value1'));
Mock::verify($mock)->test(Mock::argThat()->extractField('key2')->equals('value2'));
```